# PHP no está subiendo imágenes

Tags: php, mysql, crud

Estoy intentando crear un formulario para subir imágenes a PHP, pero me funciona todo excepto lo de subir la imagen. No me tira ningún error ni nada, pero la imagen no se está guardando. El resto si se guarda. Es decir, el nombre del artículo, el precio, la descripción se guardan, pero la imagen no. No entiendo que está pasando.

Si es necesario, acá les dejo el link al proyecto en github para que puedan revisarlo. Sencillamente no entiendo que problema hay, ya que usé el mismo código para otro proyecto y si funcionó.

El link en cuestión: https://github.com/mtfc99/headshot

Gracias!

````
if ($_POST) {
    if (isset($_POST["btnGuardar"])) {
        $nombreImagen = "";
        if ($_FILES["imagen"]["error"] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $nombreRandom = date("Ymdhmsi");
            $archivoTmp = $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"];
            $nombreArchivo = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"];
            $extension = pathinfo($nombreArchivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $nombreImagen = "$nombreRandom.$extension";
            move_uploaded_file($archivoTmp, "images/$nombreImagen");
        }

        if (isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["id"] > 0) {
            $pistolaAnt = new Pistola();
            $pistolaAnt->idpistola = $_GET["id"];
            $pistolaAnt->obtenerPorId();
            $imagenAnterior = $pistolaAnt->imagen;

            //Si es una actualizacion y se sube una imagen, elimina la anterior
            if ($_FILES["imagen"]["error"] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                if (!$imagenAnterior != "") {
                    unlink($imagenAnterior);
                }
            } else {
                //Si no viene ninguna imagen, setea como imagen la que habia previamente
                $nombreImagen = $imagenAnterior;
            }

            $pistola->imagen = $nombreImagen;
            //Actualizo un cliente existente
            $pistola->actualizar();
        } else {
            //Es nuevo
            $pistola->imagen = $nombreImagen;
            $pistola->insertar();
        }
    } else if (isset($_POST["btnBorrar"])) {
        $pistola->eliminar();
        header("Location: pistolas.php");
    }
}
?>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="txtNombre">Nombre de la Pistola</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" value="<?php echo $pistola->nombre ?>">
            </div>

            <div class=" col-md-6">
                <label for="txtPrecio">Precio de la Pistola</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtPrecio" id="txtPrecio" value="<?php echo $pistola->precio ?>">
            </div>

            <div class=" col-md-12">
                <label for="txtDescripcion">Descripción</label>
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="txtDescripcion" id="txtDescripcion"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
   <input accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen">
           
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-5" id="btnGuardar" name="btnGuardar">Guardar</button>
    </form>
</div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

no estas usando la funcion file_get_contents para obtener tu imagen, es necesaria para obtener tu imagen asi:

```
// aqui estas obteniendo tu imagen en codigo base64.
$archivoTmp = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));
//aqui obtienes el nombre de la imagen.
$nombreArchivo = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
```

Comment: En qué parte debería escribir eso?

Comment: donde obtienes tu imagen tienes que reemplazarlo con ese codigo.